# autocomplete google address api

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-places-autocomplete

I am using google autocomplete address api, it returns all the required data but not postal code. Any idea how to get postal code in api response. Below is the my url and api response returned by this api.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=19becket st  &types=address&key=my_api_key
```

data return is in following format

```
{
            "description": "19 Becket St, Boston, MA, USA",
            "matched_substrings": [
                {
                    "length": 2,
                    "offset": 0
                },
                {
                    "length": 9,
                    "offset": 3
                }
            ],
            "place_id": "ChIJN9v2H4l744kRRg9DI6ctGhY",
            "reference": "ChIJN9v2H4l744kRRg9DI6ctGhY",
            "structured_formatting": {
                "main_text": "19 Becket St",
                "main_text_matched_substrings": [
                    {
                        "length": 2,
                        "offset": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "length": 9,
                        "offset": 3
                    }
                ],
                "secondary_text": "Boston, MA, USA"
            },
            "terms": [
                {
                    "offset": 0,
                    "value": "19"
                },
                {
                    "offset": 3,
                    "value": "Becket St"
                },
                {
                    "offset": 14,
                    "value": "Boston"
                },
                {
                    "offset": 22,
                    "value": "MA"
                },
                {
                    "offset": 26,
                    "value": "USA"
                }
            ],
            "types": [
                "premise",
                "geocode"
            ]
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `place_id` to do a followup request for [place details](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details#required-parameters).

- Use the same [session token](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details#sessiontoken) for both the autocomplete requests and details requests
- Use the [fields parameter](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details#fields) in the details requests

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json
  ?fields=address_components
  &place_id=ChIJN9v2H4l744kRRg9DI6ctGhY
  &key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

The zip code will be in the [address_components](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details#Place-address_components) field of the response with type `postal_code` similar to the following:

```
{
address_components":
        [
          { "long_name": "48", "short_name": "48", "types": ["street_number"] },
          {
            "long_name": "Pirrama Road",
            "short_name": "Pirrama Rd",
            "types": ["route"],
          },
          {
            "long_name": "Pyrmont",
            "short_name": "Pyrmont",
            "types": ["locality", "political"],
          },
          {
            "long_name": "Council of the City of Sydney",
            "short_name": "Sydney",
            "types": ["administrative_area_level_2", "political"],
          },
          {
            "long_name": "New South Wales",
            "short_name": "NSW",
            "types": ["administrative_area_level_1", "political"],
          },
          {
            "long_name": "Australia",
            "short_name": "AU",
            "types": ["country", "political"],
          },
          {
            "long_name": "2009",
            "short_name": "2009",
            "types": ["postal_code"],
          },
        ],
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks, what is place_id? is place_id is unique to country or state of country? is place_id is different for different state of same country?

Comment: `place_id` is returned in the autocomplete request. Check the response in your question.